# Turn off spell checking for HTML signature in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, spell-check

Is there a way to turn off spell checking for an HTML signature added in Thunderbird? Some css style to specify, perhaps?

Context:

Thunderbird 3.1.10
Using multiple dictionaries
Using [Dictionary Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/dictionary-switcher-for-thunde/) add-on

Comment: `spellcheck=false` doesn't do anything, as far as I can tell. At least not for 3.1.10

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your spell checker is picking up on a few words in your signature, you could always just add those words to your "spell checker ignore list" to resolve the problem.

Comment: It's mostly that. Company name, my name, etc. But I'm also using multiple dictionaries, and have a bilingual signature, so that whenever I switch to another language, half of my signature is highlighted. I can live with it, but I'd like a way to make it go away, you know?

Comment: @MPelletier:  Oh yeah, having to update the spell checking dictionary for every language will be tedious, especially every time you change your signature.  =(

Comment: Ignoring words is across all dictionaries, though. So there's that.

Comment: @MPelletier:  Oh that's a good start for now at least.  You might be interested to know that the folks in the http://www.GMANE.org/ newsgroup server for the Mozilla Thunderbird newsgroups are quite active, and this might be a constructive place to post a suggestion for improving Thunderbird's Signature feature (e.g., by adding an option to exclude signatures from spell checks).

Comment: I will look them up. If Thunderbird supported HTML5's `spellcheck=false`, though, you could have that in the signature and every time it's repeated in long e-mail chains it would not trigger the spell check. Oh, the possibilities! :)

Comment: @MPelleiter:  You have a smart idea to use that HTML5 feature.